# Horizontal alignment within itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item 1. First
\item 2. Second
\item 3a. Third
\item 3b. Third
\item 4. Fourth

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

How can I horizontally align the text (First, Second, Third etc)?

Comment: this is a hack, but ..., after `1.` and the other single digit entries, insert `\phantom{b}\ ` -- you do need that final space.

Comment: Is it OK to assume that the first-level enumerate environment will never have more than nine items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new command `\myitem`

```
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
  \item\makebox[1.5em][l]{#1}%
  }
```

and use it instead of `\item` in these particular `itemize`s

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
  \item\makebox[1.5em][l]{#1}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\myitem{1.} First
\myitem{2.} Second
\myitem{3a.} Third
\myitem{3b.} Third
\myitem{4.} Fourth

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems more appropriate to use an `enumerate` environment for numeral enumeration. However, there are a number of ways to achieve this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item 1.\phantom{a}\ First
  \item \leavevmode\rlap{2.}\phantom{3a.} Second
  \item 3a.\ Third
  \item 3b.\ Third
  \item \makebox[\widthof{3a.}][l]{4.} Fourth
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

`\rlap` provides a `r`ight over`lap`, while a LaTeX2e approach would be to use `\makebox` (together with the help of [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc)'s `\widthof`). There is a mild difference in the alignment around `3a.` and `3b.`. So, depending on your level of detail, you may want to use some of the other overlapping techniques in the sub-enumeration as well.

The use of `\`  is so that the period `.` doesn't produce a sentence-ending space.

The [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) can provide similar "lapping" support.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using an automated approach using an `enumerate` environment to add the numbering:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[1.5em][r]{#1}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbullet\protect\MakeBox{\theenumi.}}]

\item First
\item Second
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbullet\protect\MakeBox{\arabic{enumi}\alph*.}}, align=right, before={\stepcounter{enumi}}, leftmargin=0pt]
    \item Third
    \item Third
\end{enumerate}
\item Fourth

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```